# UITableView Section Titles being skipped in Index

Tags: ios, uitableview

Under iOS6, my section index showed an entry for every letter in the alphabet. Now under iOS7, my table view index has the look shown below. The arrows indicate the missing sections in the index.  Note that the index does work if you tap approximately in the right spot. What has happened?  Can I restore the old behavior?

[image]

Comment: You can provide your own data source for the indexes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalizedIndexedCollation_Class/UILocalizedIndexedCollation.html

Comment: Run your app on a 4" device and you will see all letters. I have no idea why Apple is doing this now on 3.5" devices under iOS 7 but there is no way to fix it. Under iOS 6 they had no trouble showing all of the letters in the same amount of space. I suggest filing a bug report with Apple.

Comment: NSElvis: I am.   rmaddy:  The screenshot above is from a tableview in a popoverviewcontroller on iPad

Comment: I already filed a bug report for this: 15175436 on okt, 8, 2013. It was closed because I was not elaborate enough. So now I created a project to reproduce and I am trying again. The difference between iOS6 and iOS7 is remarkable. Max. 29 entries on iOS7, max 55 !! on iOS6 (on an iPad in landscape with a navigator bar, that is).

Comment: Awesome Bjinse.  Thanks for going through the process with Apple! When I don't see many other similar reports here in SO, I start to think it's me missing something obvious.